# Trim textbox text after 20 characters used and spaces if contains spaces

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinFormApp with 2 txtboxes (LongName and ShortName) with a Button.

When txt is entered in the LongName txtbox, I want to press the button to shorten all txt inside LongName txtbox to the first 20 characters imput and to remove any spaces within' the txtbox then display the results in the ShortName txtbox. I'm having a real hard time trying to get this correct. I've tried a number of ways to try but ultimately can't seem to get it right. Here is example code:

```
private void btnGetSN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex space = new Regex(@" ");
    MatchCollection spacematch = space.Matches(txtLongName.Text);
    if (txtLongName.Text.Length > 20)
    {
        string toTrim = txtLongName.Text;

        toTrim = toTrim.Trim();

        txtShortName.Text = ("'" + toTrim.ToString() + "'");
    }
    if (spacematch.Count > 0)
    {
        txtLongName.Text.Replace(" ", "");
    }
}//closes method
```

I've been able to limit the txtbox to only 20 characters in the properties but I would like to setup a If variable to allow more customization.

Am I on the right track?

No errors in the code but when executing the button, nothing happens. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are not removing spaces before you assigned to short name

Comment: This is found in the design view, as I said I've set it to 20 however I would rather have the if statement perform an action if over 20 (Trim) and not limit to

Comment: @techspider can you give an example?

Comment: You are _trying_ to remove the spaces from the long text. I have said,  _Trying_, because you don't reassign the return value of Replace to anything....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to write differently

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var shortName = txtLongName.Text.Trim().Replace(" ", "");

        var maxLength = (shortName.Length > 20) ? 20 : shortName.Length;

        if(txtLongName.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            txtShortName.Text = shortName.Substring(0, maxLength);
    }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was needing. Do you have a source that can explain this method vs mine? I would love to learn exactly why this works vs mine and when to use a method like this vs mine etc. (Learning from the mistakes is what makes me a better coder).

Comment: get a temporary shortName by removing all the characters you don't need; second get the length of current string; if it is more than 20 characters, take 20 into length; now get substring from 0 to the lenght identified in previous step; if you debug, you should be able to understand

Answer (score 4):

`string.Replace()` doesn't update the string itself, but rather returns a new string that is modified.

```
private void btnGetSN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove space from txtLongName
    txtLongName.Text = txtLongName.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

    // take only the first 20characters from txtLongName
    txtShortName.Text = txtLongName.Text.Substring(0, Math.Min(txtLongName.Text.Length, 20));
}
```

EDIT: Previous code will remove space from txtLongName. If that is not intended, use this instead :

```
private void btnGetSN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove space from txtLongName
    var name = txtLongName.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

    // take only the first 20characters from txtLongName
    txtShortName.Text = name.Substring(0, Math.Min(name.Length, 20));
}
```